# How to override style of range element using javascript

Tags: html

```
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{-webkit-appearance:none !important;width:20px;height:20px;border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px;cursor: pointer;background: url('../img/gripper.png') no-repeat;}

input[type="range"]{background-color: #B4B4B4;-webkit-appearance: none;border-radius: 8px;  -moz-border-radius: 8px;-wekkit-border-radius: 8px;}
```

using the above I can style range element but I would like to change the image height & width using jQuery.

```
$('input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb').css('width','100px');
```

is not working.

I would like to give two different colors to the path of range like

```
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {background-color: #000;}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {background-color: #B4B4B4;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Javascript for styling, the most flexible way of doing this would be assigning a class:

```
$('input[type="range"]').addClass('range');
```

CSS:

```css
.range {
    background-color: #B4B4B4;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('../img/gripper.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Also note, that you don't need vendor prefixes for `border-radius`.

Comment: Ya but It's not my question.

Comment: It **is** answer to your question, if you want to make your life easier. If not, you can go other way though.